# How to prevent a new array from being created everytime react page refreshes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo

I am trying to maintain a value of an array, `arr`, in a react component and I do not want a new array to be created with every render. That is because, I am setting `arr` as a dependency in `useMemo()`, and I do not want the callback function in `useMemo` to execute unless the actual values contained in `arr` change. However, what is actually happening and I want to prevent is that with every render, the callback function is executed. I thought of moving this array to be part of the props, is that correct?

```
let arr = ["name","age","degree"]
    useMemo(() => {
       //callback that get executed
      }, arr)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the useState hook to initialize the array and keep the value unless you use the setter to modify it.

const [arr, setArr] = useState(["name","age","degree"])